# How does the Prelude allow numeric literals for Nat?

Tags: idris, syntactic-sugar

In *Type-Driven Development with Idris* ch. 4, they say

> The Prelude also defines functions and notation to allow `Nat` to be used like any other numeric type, so rather than writing `S (S (S (S Z)))`, you can simply write `4`.

and similarly for `Fin`. How does it achieve that? I've looked at [the source](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/prelude/Prelude/Nat.idr) but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from where you linked notice [fromIntegerNat](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/0417c53fb6b91fc0692245f269b98a3bd4820136/libs/prelude/Prelude/Nat.idr#L73):

```
||| Convert an Integer to a Nat, mapping negative numbers to 0
fromIntegerNat : Integer -> Nat
fromIntegerNat 0 = Z
fromIntegerNat n =
  if (n > 0) then
    S (fromIntegerNat (assert_smaller n (n - 1)))
  else
    Z
```

and [fromInteger](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/0417c53fb6b91fc0692245f269b98a3bd4820136/libs/prelude/Prelude/Nat.idr#L241) in the Num implementation of Nat:

```
Num Nat where
  (+) = plus
  (*) = mult

  fromInteger = fromIntegerNat
```

and Cast Integer Nat

```
||| Casts negative `Integers` to 0.
Cast Integer Nat where
  cast = fromInteger
```

In the case of Idris1 it will attempt to cast from a literal (such as Char, String or Integer) into whatever type is required via those "fromFunctions" (as noted in a comment in one of the above sources: `[...] '-5' desugars to 'negate (fromInteger 5)'`) and in general Idris1 supports implicit casting for any two types. ( http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/miscellany.html#implicit-conversions )

In the case of Idris2, there are some [pragmas](https://github.com/edwinb/Idris2/blob/4fe2018d93d5eb7da171655c4574e764a49e6e01/src/Idris/Parser.idr#L1036) (`%charLit fromChar`, `%stringLit fromString`, `%integerLit fromInteger`) to hint the compiler to use some cast function from a literal into any other type.